# Flutter: How to change length of Slider

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-slider

I am trying to use a slider but it is not taking up the available space there is. I have no margins or paddings around it for it to not take up available space. I added a screenshot and my code below. I also want to make the track thinner and an outline on the thumb. But the main thing right now is to make the slider wider or fill up the available space that's on it's right.

[image]

**rating_screen.dart**

```
Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 15),
                width: screenWidth * 0.8,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Rate your experience',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black54,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Drag',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                              color: Colors.black45),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: screenHeight * 0.02),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          height: 40,
                          width: 40,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Color(0xFFFF2424),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                          ),
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.sentiment_very_satisfied,
                            color: Colors.white54,
                            size: 30,
                          ),
                        ),
                        RatingSlider(),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

**Slider**

```
class _RatingSliderState extends State<RatingSlider> {
  double value = 50;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Slider(
        value: value,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        divisions: 4,
        activeColor: Colors.red,
        inactiveColor: Colors.black38,
        onChanged: (value) => setState(() => this.value = value),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your slider widget with `Expanded`. It will take available space.

```dart
 Expanded( child: RatingSlider(),),
```

Comment: Okay, that did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help, Slider adapt the parent size